# how to check if div exist and greater then four div different style apply on each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on asp.net mvc and I have partial view where products are displayed using a foreach loop on product views. 
My requirement is little bit different :  if there are more than 4 products, then the display must change. For the moment, each product is shown differently, how can I do this ?

Just like below image each product show differently :
[image]

---

Here is my current code :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="item-box"> 
        <div class="category-item"> 
            <h2class="title">
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">@item.Name </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="picture"> 
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title"> 
                    <img alt="@item.PictureModel.AlternateText"src="@item.PictureModel.ImageUrl" title="@item.PictureModel.Title" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your html.

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model){<div class="item-box"> <div class="category-item"> <h2class="title"><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">@item.Name </a></h2><div class="picture"> <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title"> <img alt="@item.PictureModel.AlternateText"src="@item.PictureModel.ImageUrl" title="@item.PictureModel.Title" /></a></div></div></div>}

Comment: i want show images like above image. in this html all product show same

Comment: You should add different CSS classes to your divs depending on the number of items, **from your ASP.NET code**. You shouldn't rely on Javascript for this.